# Replace quotes in xml string

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I have a problem with double quotes in classic ASP.

I want to replace double quotes " in a string.  The string contains xml and I don't want to replace double quotes (for attributes) inside tags.

So if I wanted to replace double quotes with single quotes, I'd want my string to go from this:

```
<MyDinosaurDocument DocType="Brachysaurus">"Hello" said the little dinosaur</MyDinosaurDocument>
```

to this:

```
<MyDinosaurDocument DocType="Brachysaurus">'Hello' said the little dinosaur</MyDinosaurDocument>
```

I've tried using regular expressions and would like to fix this problem with them -- but I'm sadly out of my depth.

All and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use Regex to solve this problem.  Here is a simple chunk of code that would do it:-

```
Dim dom : Set dom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")

dom.LoadXml myXMLString

Dim node
For Each node in dom.SelectNodes("//*/text()")
    node.nodeValue = Replace(node.nodeValue, """", "'")
Next

myXMLString = dom.xml
```

Of course you probably at some point need to load the XML into a DOM anyway so once that is done there is no need to read the string back out.

Comment: Gerrie and Konrad, thanks for your replies.  Anthony that does exactly what I want - pertect, thanks!

Comment: @adrianos: well, accept his answer, then! (tick mark next to the question, and don’t forget to upvote it, too)

Comment: ah sorry - hope that's sorted now (can you tell it's my first time on here?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `&quot;` to escape quotes in XML.

Answer (score 0):

As always when dealing with non-regular data, the answer is not to use a regular expression. Really, don’t. XML and HTML should always be parsed by appropriate parsers and furthermore ASP gives you the means to do this easily. Using regular expressions here is a [**serious** security liability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166).